Why is a seemingly random font showing up in Chrome?
For some reason the "Open Sans" font family ends up computing to a random font in Chromium based browsers. On Firefox this doesn't happen at all but for Chromium I can see "Edwardian Scr ITC TT" as the computer font family from a local source.
However that's nonsense.
I uninstalled the driver. I stopped the font cache service. Deleted the font cache files from my PC. Restarted Windows and still it's showing this weird font. It's happening on all Chromium browsers too, not just one. But again, Firefox has no issue.
Am I missing something to fix this?


I finally fixed it. Despite all of my Chromium browsers showing "Edwardian Scr ITC TT" as the font family this was a complete lie.
What finally got me what I needed was trying to find any font on my PC that had an empty PostScript name. As shown in my screenshot above the PostScript name was empty for whatever reason.
So I ran this code snippet from my Chromium browser's console:
try {
  const availableFonts = await window.queryLocalFonts();
  for (const fontData of availableFonts) {
    if (fontData.postscriptName == "") {
        console.log(fontData);
    }
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.name, err.message);
}

Which revealed the true culprit was "Easy Street EPS Bold" which can actually be seen in my screen shot above. I deleted that font and my problem was solved.
